# Acknowledging pubsub messages through python synchronous pull does not work

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

With the python `google-cloud-pubsub` library, acknowledging messages through the `subscriber.acknowledge()` does not acknowledge my messages. My ack deadline is set at 30 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

project_id = "$$$$"
subscription_name = "$$$$" 
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_name)

response = subscriber.pull(subscription_path, max_messages=10, timeout=15)

for msg in response.received_messages:
    subscriber.acknowledge(subscription=subscription_path, ack_ids=[msg.ack_id])
```

Using `google-cloud-pubsub==1.0.2`

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How can you tell the messages are not acknowledged?

Comment: My pubsub subscription's number of unacked messages stays the same! I see this through the UI or via stackdriver

Comment: I don't have an exact answer but just a guess, sync it's a synchronous call, and what you do there is basically while iterating over the messages from the subscriber it might not actually finish the pull operation because the iterator might fetch more messages as you iterate over. Try to have something like: `ack_ids=[]; for msg in msgs: ack_ids.append(msg.ack_id);` and after finishing the loop call the `subscriber.acknowledge()`.

Comment: Good thought but same problem if I iterate through the iterator.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend you is referring to [Synchronous Pull documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull), then run a sample code in Python to pull and acknowledge messages:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

project_id = "Your Google Cloud Project ID"
TODO subscription_name = "Your Pub/Sub subscription name"

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
    project_id, subscription_name)

NUM_MESSAGES = 3
response = subscriber.pull(subscription_path, max_messages=NUM_MESSAGES)

ack_ids = []
for received_message in response.received_messages:
    print("Received: {}".format(received_message.message.data))
    ack_ids.append(received_message.ack_id)

subscriber.acknowledge(subscription_path, ack_ids)

print('Received and acknowledged {} messages. Done.'.format(
    len(response.received_messages)))
```

I can't find definition of `ack_ids = []` in your code (you need to define it before starting use it in code). If you will see positive results when running that piece of code, you can assume that there is a bug in your code. Have you provided a full code?